# plyr::ddply equivalent in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I personally learned `plyr` prior to `dplyr`, and I'm trying to normalize my code into the `dplyr` syntax wherever possible, but I get stuck with the following use-case:

```
ddply(
    .data = somedataframe, 
    .variables = c('var1', 'var2'),
    .function = 
        function(thisdf){
            ...
        }
)
```

Where the `...` inside the function call is some *arbitrarily complex modification of the dataframe*. Note that the choice of `ddply` versus `dlply` (or anyother `dxply`) is purely for illustration. Does a function within `dplyr` exists (call it `dplyr::f` for the moment), that could also take an arbitrary modification function? For example:

```
somedataframe %>% 
    group_by(var1, var2) %>% 
    dplyr::f(.function = function(thisdf){ ... })
```

In my investigation of this functionality, all the examples that I could find were extremely simple `summarise` implementations of `ddply`.

Comment: I think the just released update to dplyr has some additional grouping verbs such as `group_by_map` that attempt to cover this kind of thing.

Comment: Sorry, it's `group_map` and you can read about it [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/02/dplyr-0-8-0/). The older way of doing this sort of thing in dplyr (that still works, I believe) is `do()`.

Comment: If you want to modify dataframe use mutate

Comment: you're not very far from a reproducible example, just give us a data set and a real function, with the expected output, and you'll get a great answer in no time and will help more people with the same issue.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper - joran has sufficiently answered the question in his comment

Comment: It's still useful for future readers to have a reproducible example and answer to follow. The current state of the question is not that helpful for others.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the simplest way is using the `dplyr::do()` function but one can also use the `group_modify()`. Complete example:

```
library(tidyverse)

#some complex function
func = function(x) {
  mod = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = x)
  mod_coefs = broom::tidy(mod)

  tibble(
    mean_sepal_length = mean(x$Sepal.Length),
    mean_petal_width = mean(x$Petal.Width), 
    slope = mod_coefs[[2, 2]],
    slope_p = mod_coefs[[2, 5]]
  )
}

#plyr version
plyr::ddply(iris, "Species", func)

#dplyr with do()
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  do(func(.))

#dplyr with group_map()
#have to rewrite the function to take a second argument, which is the grouping variable
func2 = function(x, y) {
  mod = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = x)
  mod_coefs = broom::tidy(mod)

  tibble(
    mean_sepal_length = mean(x$Sepal.Length),
    mean_petal_width = mean(x$Petal.Width), 
    slope = mod_coefs[[2, 2]],
    slope_p = mod_coefs[[2, 5]]
  )
}

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_modify(func2)
```

These produce:

```
     Species mean_sepal_length mean_petal_width     slope      slope_p
1     setosa             5.006            0.246 0.9301727 5.052644e-02
2 versicolor             5.936            1.326 1.4263647 4.035422e-05
3  virginica             6.588            2.026 0.6508306 4.798149e-02

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Species    mean_sepal_length mean_petal_width slope   slope_p
  <fct>                  <dbl>            <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 setosa                  5.01            0.246 0.930 0.0505   
2 versicolor              5.94            1.33  1.43  0.0000404
3 virginica               6.59            2.03  0.651 0.0480   

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Species    mean_sepal_length mean_petal_width slope   slope_p
  <fct>                  <dbl>            <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 setosa                  5.01            0.246 0.930 0.0505   
2 versicolor              5.94            1.33  1.43  0.0000404
3 virginica               6.59            2.03  0.651 0.0480
```

There are 2 differences. The `ddply()` output is a standard data frame, even though the function outputted a tibble. The **dplyr** outputs are grouped tibbles, despite the grouping had been 'used'.

Comment: Current versions of group_map return a list of tibbles. The right verb is group_modify it seems.