# Make plyr::ddply code compatible with dplyr-equivalent custom function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, pipe, plyr

I am attempting to adapt a long function (`rcompanion::groupwiseMean`) to use `dplyr` instead of `plyr::ddply` in its code to avoid dependency on the now deprecated `plyr` package.

I would like to define a custom `ddply2` function, taking the same arguments as the original `plyr` function, but with `dplyr` under the hood. The benefit would be to only redefine the function once at the top of the existing long function/script without changing anything else. My attempts have failed so far. Demo below.

I have been using this resource: [plyr::ddply equivalent in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54774280/plyrddply-equivalent-in-dplyr)

### Original `plyr:ddplyr` call

```r
data <- mtcars
var <- "mpg"
group <- c("cyl", "am")

# Original plyr:ddply-fed function:
fun.y <- function(x, idx) { length(x[, idx]) }

# Original plyr:ddply call:
plyr::ddply(.data = data, .variables = group, var, .fun = fun.y)
#>   cyl am V1
#> 1   4  0  3
#> 2   4  1  8
#> 3   6  0  4
#> 4   6  1  3
#> 5   8  0 12
#> 6   8  1  2
```

### This is the function that I CANNOT rewrite

```
fun.y <- function(x, idx) { length(x[, idx]) }
```

However this is just an example. Here are some other functions I will need working with `ddply2`:

```
fun.z <- function(x, idx) { as.numeric(mean(x[, idx], trim = trim, na.rm = na.rm)) }
fun.w <- function(x, idx) {
      mean(boot(x[, idx], function(y, j) mean(y[j], trim = trim,
                                              na.rm = na.rm), R = R, ...)$t[, 1])
}
```

Now let's proceed to the desired `ddply2` call, which I am allowed to modify any way I want. However it must take the same arguments as `plyr::ddply`.

### Attempt to rewrite `plyr:ddply` as `dpply2`

```r
library(dplyr)

ddply2 <- function(.data, .variables, var, .fun) {
  .data %>%
    group_by(across({{.variables}})) %>%
    do(.fun(., {{var}}))
}

ddply2(.data = data, .variables = group, var, .fun = fun.y)
# Error in `do()`:
# ! Results 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 must be data frames, not integer.
```

### Edit

Again, I cannot rewrite `fun.y`, `fun.z`, or `fun.w`, only `ddply2`. So solutions based on `summarize()` or `count()` will not work as they are not generalizable to other functions. `plyr:ddplyr` did not require `summarize()` or `count()`, that's the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some discussion I now understand that what is desired is to rewrite this function using dplyr rather than plyr such that for inputs such as those listed in the inputs section below it gives the same result.

```
dd <- function(data, group, var, fun) 
  plyr::ddply(.data = data, .variables = group, var, .fun = fun)
```

To do that the new function can use group_by with either summarize or group_modify.  dd1 below uses the first and dd2 uses the second.  Use whichever you prefer.

Note that the way fun.z was written it assumes a data frame and not a tibble (because data frames return a vector if there is only one column whereas tibble returns another tibble) so we use as.data.frame to ensure that.  Also plyr returns a data frame and at the end of dd1 and dd2 we convert the tibble produced to data frame to ensure that the result is identical.

```
dd1 <- function(data, group, var, fun)
  data %>% 
    group_by(across(all_of(group))) %>%
    summarize(V1 = fun(as.data.frame(cur_data()), var), .groups = "drop") %>%
    as.data.frame

dd2 <- function(data, group, var, fun)
  data %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(group))) %>%
    group_modify(~ { data.frame(V1 = fun(as.data.frame(.), var)) }) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    as.data.frame
```

Now test it out

```
# inputs - start #

data <- mtcars
trim <- 0
na.rm <- FALSE
var <- "mpg"
group <- c("cyl", "am")

fun.z <- function(x, idx) { 
  as.numeric(mean(x[, idx], trim = trim, na.rm = na.rm))
}

# inputs - end #

library(dplyr)

dd.out <- dd(data, group, var, fun.z) # plyr
dd1.out <- dd1(data, group, var, fun.z)
dd2.out <- dd2(data, group, var, fun.z)

identical(dd1.out, dd.out)
## [1] TRUE

identical(dd2.out, dd.out)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I'm sorry I know my question is quite confusing but I don't know how I can make it clearer. It seems to me that you have provided the "level 1" (the final result for a single example) while I'm looking for "level 2" (i.e., defining a general-purpose function). I'm not looking to change the function fed to `plyr::ddply` like in your examples, but to rewrite `plyr::ddply` without reliance on the `plyr` package so it can take code written for `plyr::ddply`  without changes. Perhaps I should call it `ddply2` for clarity. Let me do that actually.

Comment: Ok, let me play with this for a bit and I will see if I can solve my problem completely. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so the function that I *cannot* rewrite is: `fun.y = function(x, idx) { length(x[, idx]) }`. Based on your answer, I defined `ddply2` as such: `ddply2 <- function(.data, .variables, group, .fun, ...) {  aggregate(.data[.variables], .data[group], .fun) }`. Then I attempt to apply fun.y: `ddply2(.data = data, .variables = group, var, .fun = fun.y)` results in: `Error in x[, idx] : incorrect number of dimensions`. Same with the fun.z from my post. The output I am looking for is a *function* called `ddply2`. I cannot rely on `count()` or `summarize()` as these were only simplified examples.

Comment: I am aware that my question was confusing and needlessly long so I have greatly shortened it so hopefully it will be a lot clearer now.

Comment: The example you provided with `summarize` is exactly what I wrote in my original question. I explained that I cannot consistently use `summarize` in `ddply2` because it needs to accommodate other custom functions. For example, would your solution work with these two other functions? `fun.y <- function(x, idx) { length(x[, idx]) }` and `fun.w <- function(x, idx) { mean(boot(x[, idx], function(y, j) mean(y[j], trim = trim, na.rm = na.rm), R = R, ...)$t[, 1]) }`. Also, could you modify your answer to define a `ddply2` function?

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for your patience and for hanging around. Your solution works great for `fun.z`, `fun.y` and `fun.w` and the other more complex functions I required. I was surprised it works with `summarize` in addition to `group_modify`. Kudos for providing both options and rewriting your answer. It is really well written and explained now. I'm sure your answer will be helpful to other people transitioning code from `plyr` to `dplyr`.

Comment: Note: it's interesting to me that we need to use `!!!syms` as relevant documentation states that it is "no longer for normal usage, but still exported from dplyr for backward compatibility." And recommended alternatives are double brackets or `{{}}` or `.data[[var]]` but I've tried both and they surprisingly don't work in the current context.

Comment: Here's the final call I used to make it identical to `plyr::ddply` to replace it in the original script without any additional change: 

`ddply <- function(.data, .variables, var, .fun, ...) {.data %>% group_by(!!!syms(.variables)) %>% summarize(V1 = .fun(as.data.frame(cur_data()), var), .groups = "drop") %>% as.data.frame }`

Comment: The curly-curly operators expect symbols and lists of symbols, not character vectors.

Comment: Have replaced !!!syms with across.